# What does this lyric in a song mean?

Tags: grammar, translation

> わたしのことなんて、見てくれないの

Does this directly translate to:

> Won't you look at a thing such as I?

Comment: It's a statement, not a question. Kind of like "you won't even look at/acknowledge me". If it was a question it would be「わたしの事なん"で"見てくれないの (Why won't you look at/acknowledge me?)」.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

の at sentence end can be a (feminine) way to add emotional emphasis. Especially in this situation when there is also なんて before it expressing despise towards わたし.

As Genos said in comments, the whole thing means "you won't even look at/acknowledge me". Also I'm assuming we're talking about [this](http://vocaloidlyrics.wikia.com/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%82%A7%E3%83%81%E3%82%A7%E3%83%BB%E3%83%81%E3%82%A7%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AF%E3%83%B3%E3%83%84%E3%83%BC%EF%BC%81_(Check_Check_One_Two!)) song and you can see that it's not a question:

> わたしのことなんて、見てくれないの (and you won’t spare me a single glance)

You weren't completely wrong thinking that の means a question. Here's how の can be used as a question:

> (rising tone at end) そうなの？ Is that so?

Comment: Hmm I see. Could you explain why it means that? Is it similar to でも？

Comment: @TylerH what is similar to でも? の? No I don't think so

Comment: なんて similar? Since in this situation it means even?

Comment: @TylerH The translation in your question "a thing such as I" is very unnatural but if you don't make it a question it's about right. More generally なんて means using something (わたし here) as an example and indirectly expressing despise towards it or similar things in general. I'm struggling to come up with a good example, but think something like "**to hell with the likes of** me"

Comment: Hmm ok thank you. So a direct translation would be "You dont look at things like me"

Comment: @TylerH Or since we're talking about a person, "You won't look at a (pathetic) person like me"

Comment: I would like to add that although intonation is very important with the の, なんて is what really makes this sentence a statement. Change it to なんで and you got yourself a question.

Comment: @siikamiika Good explanation. Wasn't sure I could explain the whole thing properly so I put my two cents in the comments.